# How do I administer search in SharePoint 2007 vs 2010?

Tags: 2007, search

Please provide some links that explain where to access Search Administration in SharePoint 2007?

How does it differ from SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a pretty good overview of the new search capabilities:

**Reference**:

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/05/03/new-sp2010-search-capabilities-overview/.  (broken link).